# Compiler warning on seemingly compatible function pointer assignment (const vs no-const)

Tags: c

I ran into something funny that I think should be valid. Firstly:

Compiler/Version

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
```

Compiler options and warning message.

```
$ gcc -c warn.c -o warn.o
warn.c:11:5: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
warn.c:11:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘foo.exec’) [enabled by default]
```

I want to know why 'Foo()' is incompatible with 'exec'. (Added comments to hope-fully clarity)

```
typedef struct Thing
{
    void (*exec)(char *abc);
} Thing;

// ME: I don't mess with this.. I make const, K?
void Foo(const char *abc)
{
    (void) abc;
}

// GCC: LOL, nope! probably u messed up.
Thing foo = { Foo };
```

Comment: For the same reason that you can't define a function in a header like `void myTest(char * t);` and implement it like `void myTest(const char *t){}`. They are that, two different type of functions not interchangeable.

Comment: However its just a warning and not an error. The apparent reasoning behind it as explained [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18458984/319204).

Answer (score 4):

`const char *` is not the same as `char *`.

From the C-standard 6.7.5.3 (emphasis by me):

> 15 For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible return types.  Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are present, shall agree in the number of
>   parameters and in use of the ellipsis terminator; **corresponding parameters shall have
>   compatible types**. [...]

From the C-standard 6.7.5.1 (emphasis by me):

> 2 For two pointer types **to be compatible**, both shall be **identically qualified** and both shall
>   be pointers to compatible types.

Note: `const` is a `qualifier`

Comment: I am unable to understand why can't the functor 'void (*fptr)(const char *)` work for both the types of functions with `char *` and `const char *`

Comment: @UchiaItachi: Because they are of different types. One is taking `const char *` the other is taking `char *`.

Comment: Ok, in the OP it's not the *type* that is different, but it's *qualifiers*. However to be *compatible* even the later needs to be the same.

Comment: @alk Another case for 2 function types to be compatible is when one of them does NOT specify the parameter type list. In the C-standard quoted above, the phrase "**if both are present**" can be emphasised to highlight this.

Comment: But, 
const int*p; int *q;
p = q; I get no warning here and Both are not identically qualified.

Comment: @UchiaItachi `p` and `q` in your example are pointers to data and not function-pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Basically your function `void Foo(const char *abc)` says that I will `not modify` the variable which I point to.

But the functor int srtuct `void (*exec)(char *abc)` says I `might/mightnot modify` the variable.

This isn't acceptable.

Comment: As the compiler doesn't know if a variable may or may not change, why warn me when the parameter is 'const' if it doesn't matter? (Especially since 'const' is no guarantee anyway)

Answer (score 2):

It is just the compiler finding a mismatch in the function-signatures and issuing a warning and not an error since the function **call** will work just fine at runtime(same type/size/number of function params).

> The apparent reason behind the warning is to help the programmer identify situations where the function-pointer is accidentally being assigned a function that co-incidentally accepts the same parameters but is distinctly different in its operation.
>
> In the current example, the compiler can identify this based on the difference in intent implied by the **`const`** modifier applied to the function parameter.

---

Basically when you define the `struct` as follows,

```
typedef struct Thing
{
    void (*exec)(char *abc);
} Thing;
```

You are explicitly telling the compiler that the function pointer should point to only functions that match a specific signature (parameters and return-type).

This **warning is easily fixed** by updating the `struct` definition as follows

```
typedef struct Thing
{
    void (*exec)(const char *abc);
} Thing;
```

or **can be completely side-stepped** by not specifying the params at all

```
typedef struct Thing
{
    void (*exec)();
} Thing;
```

in which case the compiler will NOT issue a warning as long as the return type constraint is satisfied.

Comment: @JonPurdy In C++, not in C. Right?

Comment: The interface code is actually legacy, and many implementation's do and don't modify the parameters in question. Unless the 'const' could introduce an undesired effect (read bug), what reason would I receive a warning for my assignment?

Comment: The warning is just a hint for the programmer to "double-check" the assignment. The compiler here is simply giving a warning that maybe (just maybe) you are performing this assignment by mistake since the function pointer seems to have a different intent than the actual function being assigned. The intent is different here due to the mismatching `const` modifier. In your case, you can safely ignore this warning due to mismatch of `const`. However it is better to update the definition of the function pointer within the struct to use a `const` parameter as well (if you can).

Comment: @TheCodeArtist: Sorry, I didn’t notice that the question was not tagged [tag:c++].

Answer (score 0):

A mere assignment in this direction would be ok, such as

```
char * a = <whatever>;
const char * b = a;
```

but in a function signature, rules are stricter than on an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of your function `foo` and the function pointer `exec` are different.

The compiler knows the variable is const and depending on the compiler, the compiler may do some optimizations.