# Does const mismatch invoke UB when pointer argument is received by va_arg?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, variadic-functions

I noticed some potential issue with `va_arg` macro, that is used to receive an unnamed parameter from variadic function. Consider following, simplified example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void foo(int n, ...)
{
    va_list ap;  
    const char *s;

    va_start(ap, n);
    for (s = va_arg(ap, const char *); *s != '\0'; s++)
        putchar(*s);
    va_end(ap);
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "xyz";
    foo(1, str);
    return 0;
}
```

The reference for [`va_arg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg) macro states that (emphasis mine):

> If va_arg is called when there are no more arguments in ap, or if the
>   type of the next argument in ap (after promotions) **is not compatible
>   with T, the behavior is undefined** (...)

My understanding is that `const char *` and `char *` types are *not* compatible. When `char` array is passed to the `foo`, in form of `char` pointer (that is unchanged by default argument promotions), then the expression, that assumes const-qualified pointer:

```
s = va_arg(ap, const char *)
```

could invoke "technical" UB. The same situation would arise, when `arr` is defined as `const` array, and the argument is received as `char *`, as well as for other types e.g. `int *` and `const int *`.

Comment: In that case, not compatible is a size issue, not a `const` issue. when size is incorrect, you shift the va_args scan and it crashes badly. Had it once when passing 0 instead of `NULL` on a 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 6.2.7 of the [C11 language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) defines *type compatibility*, section 6.7.6.1 further specifies it for pointer declarators and section 6.7.3 for type qualifiers.  The latter (constraint 10) says:

> For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the
>   identically qualified version of a compatible type; the order of type
>   qualifiers within a list of specifiers or qualifiers does not affect
>   the specified type.

Also, section 6.7.6.1 says:

> For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.

According to these two, I understand that `const char*` and `char*` are not compatible (because `const char` and `char` are not compatible).  According to the definition of `va_arg` in section 7.16.1.1 which requires type compatibility (with a couple of exceptions that do not apply here), I believe that indeed you have undefined behavior in this case.

Now, if we stop playing the lawyer, I don't see how it could be harmful to treat a `char*` as a `const char*` --- it would only limit the legal operations.  Therefore, I believe that the specification of `va_arg` is too conservative.

Comment: I already upvoted, but I agree for sure that the section about `va_arg` could do with a clarification for this

Answer (score 3):

[n1570/6.2.5p28](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28) seems to suggest this should be okay in practice:

> ...Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements...

Since `char` is compatible with itself, a pointer to char will have the same representation as a pointer to a const char. Since a variable argument function essentially assumes a representation of each subsequent parameter, this appears at first well defined.

As for the other way around, if you use a pointer to char so as to modify a const char, that is indeed UB per [n1570/6.7.3p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p6):

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

---

To continue the analysis from the answer you linked to in the comments, [n1570/6.7.6.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.1p2):

> For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.

Since both pointer types are themselves non const, they are identically qualified, the only question that remains is if `const char` is compatible with `char` for our purposes.

And it appears that they are not... as nickie pointed out. So on the one hand, this could be construed as UB.

Comment: I agree that there's no real problem here, because the two pointers are bound to have identical representations.  But if it were the other way round (a `const char*` treated as a `char*` and possibly assigned to), I'd be more happy with undefined behavior.  According to the standard, however, it seems that this is not a matter of representation but of type compatibility, as defined there.

Comment: My assumption was based by  C11 6.7.3/10: `For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version of a compatible type;`, as well as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18458745/586873) answer. Neverthless, I agree, that it is more like theoretical issue, because the `const` representation is the same, as you pointed out.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski - But you do not have two qualified types. The pointers are not qualified, only the pointees are. The standard is too vague on this...

Comment: @StoryTeller: What about C11 6.7.6.1/2: `For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall
be pointers to compatible types.`? This would indicate that `char *` and `const char *` are not compatible types.

Comment: Yes, @GrzegorzSzpetkowski, that's what I think too.  (End of lawyer mode.)

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski - Yes, it would seem so. Since when you follow the rabbit down the hole it all boils down to the paragraph nickie quoted. I wish the standard committee would address this, if they don't plan to already...

Comment: I'm upvoting @StoryTeller's answer because I agree that, in practice, this program should be safe and the standard for `va_arg` should be made less conservative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are not compatible and using va_arg with type const char* when the actual type is char*, and vice-versa, is undefined behavior.

A type is only compatible with itself<sup>1</sup>.

Additionally, the section on qualifiers, const being one, supports this<sup>2</sup>.

---

(Quoted from ISO/IEC 9899:201x)

<sup>1</sup> (6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type 1)
Two types have compatible type if their types are the same

<sup>2</sup> (6.7.3 Type qualifiers 10)
For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version
of a compatible type; the order of type qualifiers within a list of specifiers or qualifiers
does not affect the specified type.